# Python logging printing double to console

Tags: python-3.x, logging

It seems that on a couple machines I'm getting double output like this:

```
INFO LED NOTIFICATION STARTED
INFO:output_logger:LED NOTIFICATION STARTED
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO, ContentFormat='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', DateTimeFormat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", CreateConsoleLogger=False):
    """Function setup as many loggers as you want"""

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    if CreateConsoleLogger:
        # create console handler
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(level)
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(message)s")
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

    # create a file handler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=2000000, backupCount=5)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(ContentFormat, DateTimeFormat)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

This is how I'm creating the logger:

```
output_logger = setup_logger('output_logger', 'log/autofy.log', level=logging.DEBUG, CreateConsoleLogger=True)
```

And this is how I call it:

```
output_logger.info("LED NOTIFICATION STARTED")
```

On a most of computers I just see the same message printed to the console that's saved to the file as expected `("INFO LED NOTIFICATION STARTED")`, but on other computers it's doing this weird double output thing.  My code is exactly the same from one computer to another, so any ideas what could be causing this on some computers and not others?

## EDIT

I'm writing the script using notepad++ and running it in a terminal window on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  I'm using python3.

Comment: What are your IDEs in both cases?

Comment: My apologies - I'm just using notepad++ and running in a terminal window in Ubuntu 16.04.  I'm using python3.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
logging._get_logger().propagate = False
```